# jackson deserialize unknown property name to custom entity

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a yaml file using jackson, which works similar to Json, so for convenience i'm going to use Json.

My Json structure looks like this :

```
 {
    "version": "2",
    "services": {
        "app": {
            "build": {
                "context": "./",
                "args": {}
            },
            "image": "imageName"
        },
        "results": {
            "build": "./",
            "image": "imageName"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to deserialize this using jackson, but I am getting UnknownPropertyException when using the default ObjectMapper.

This is the class I am trying to deserialize to :

```
public class ServiceModel {

List<ContainerModel> containers;

public List<ContainerModel> getContainers() {
    return containers;
}

public void setContainers(List<ContainerModel> containers) {
    this.containers = containers;
}
}
```

My container model looks something like this :

```
public class ContainerModel {

@JsonProperty("build")
private String build;

@JsonProperty("args")
private List<String> args;

@JsonProperty("context")
private String context;

@JsonProperty("dockerfile")
private String dockerFile;

// Getters and Setters below
```

**EDIT : I was wrong in describing the Json Structure. Please look at the corrected Json structure that jackson generated when I mapped it to JsonNode**

Here, app and results are supposed to be mapped to ContainerModel

Comment: Can you provide (parts of) the class you are deserializing to?

Comment: @nyname00 please look at the edit. thanks

Comment: @r0shi, can you also post `ContainerModel`?

Comment: @Casey Added the ContainerModel. It doesn't have any custom Objects, and the property names are also known so I would assume that won't be such a big problem

Comment: I'm guessing the 'build' property in 'app' is not supposed to contain 'context' and 'args'. And also, there is no 'image' property in your class. Is is supposed to be 'dockerFile'?

Comment: No, the build property can be either a String property or a map of other properties. yes, image is to be ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Looking at your new Json structure the ServiceModel class should look like this:

```
public class ServiceModel {
    private String version;
    private Map<String, ContainerModel> containers;
    // Other fields here...

    public void setContainers(Map<String, ContainerModel> containers) {
        this.containers = containers;
    }

    public Map<String, ContainerModel> getContainers() {
        return containers;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    // Other setters/getters here...
}
```

This way you get your mapping from a key (String), to a ContainerModel.

**Original Post**

Well, your Json example has a property called `services`, and your class has a property called `containers`. You shouldn't expect an automatic mapping between those properties.

To map them automatically, use the same property names. If you don't want to, or can't, you can always use Jackson's annotation `@JsonProperty`.
Additionally, if there are fields that you don't want mapped, you should instantiate a new ObjectMapper, and configure it to ignore unknown fields. Like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Also, I am assuming that you get the exception mapping the ServiceModel class, and not the `//Known data structure`. But in any case my suggestion should solve the issue in both cases.

Comment: I have a wrapper for services also which maps the the ServiceModel, so I would assume that's not the problem. The problem arises when mapping var1 to ContainerModel

Comment: Ah! I see. Then your structure does not seem accurate, to me. It should be something like: "services": [ {ContainerModel element here}, {another ContainerModel element here}]

Comment: yeah, but how do I map it if I don't know the key (and it's designed to have any key)

Comment: Then, a list like you have in the ServiceModel class is not the proper structure. I'm guessing that what you want is a map? `Map<String, ContainerModel>` maybe?

Comment: this fixed part of the problem I was having in getting a ContainerModel instance. The problem now is how to bind build which can either be a String, or a Dict. 

edit:  I guess I might have to write a custom serializer for it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to deserialize a property that doesn't exist.

By default, Jackson will throw an exception when you try to deserialize an unknown property. You can disable this by adding the following to your `ObjectMapper` instance:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

You'll likely want to fix the unknown property though. It is likely the `services` property, which you've declared as `containers` in your Java class.

Comment: Well, The container property exists, It's just that the name for it it unknown

Comment: Is the array `services` a list of `ServiceModel` instances or `ContainerModel` instances?

Comment: the array services is a list of ContainerModel Instances, although If needed, I can totally eliminate ServiceModel and use List<ContainerModel> in the wrapper model which currently stores the services array. 

I am basically writing a parser for docker-compose.yml if you are familiar to that and want to have a full reference of the structure

Comment: Take a look at the last edit, I believe that will resolve your issue.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, please look at the edit. It should be a bit more clearer now.

Comment: It looks like the unknown property is `image`, do you have that in your `ContainerModel`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why a list of maps?

Comment: @pca, the original JSON required the keys to be dynamic (OP says it can be any key in a different comment). It seems the JSON was updated now, so that part of my answer is no longer valid.

Comment: If you were asking why a `List` instead of just the `Map`, the original JSON had `{{"key1": {}}, {"key2":{}}`, which would be a list of 1 item maps.